# Converting Application/octet-stream to Base64 string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, salesforce-lightning, pdf.js, lightning

I am trying to render a PDF using PDFJS Library. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

We are receiving Content-type as "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8" like below from an API that we are calling within javascript from our HTML.
But PDF JS is not able to use app/octet stream directly. Is there any way to natively get base64 from the octet stream in Javascript,so it can be used by PDFJS.

PDF JS can directly use base64 string : https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/cq0asLqz/

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/Pages 2 0 R
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
```

Comment: Try `multer`. You can find it on npm

Comment: We are using plain Javascript and html in the application. NPM will not be a possibility for us

Comment: I don't know how to do it in plain javascript. But in react I would use `URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile)` the use it as `src`

Comment: did you find any solution to it ?